# tcolorbox is not transparent

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to get a transparent `tcolorbox` but it does not seem to work. This is an example in its documentation (page 2013 for `tcolorbox` 6.0.1)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Transparent box, tikz={opacity=0.1,transparency group}]
    This is a tcolorbox.
\end{tcolorbox}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: add `enhanced,` or some other skin which does support that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This works. Thanks. It seems I removed `enhanced` option